# [Part of a system of linear equations!]: Find $B$ such that $A = B\times C$, but $C\times C'$ is non-invertable

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following Equation:

$A = B\times C$

- $A$ is a $(N\times 1)$ Known Matrix
- $B$ is a $(N\times M)$ Unknown Matrix, where $N>M$
- $C$ is a $(M\times 1)$ Known Matrix
- $C\times C'$ is a non-invertible $(M\times M)$ Matrix

Now if we are interested in finding Matrix $C$, this would be the solution for a system of linear equations. However, in my case $C$ is known but Matrix $B$ is not. I am not familiar with how to deal with such a problem because $(C\times C')$ is not invertible.

Please advise me on how to find a closed-form solution to Matrix $B$

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Think of $B$ as corresponding to a linear transformation from $\mathbb F^M$ to $\mathbb F^N$, 
where $\mathbb F$ is the field you're working over (presumably $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$).  Your equation specifies $B C = A$, where $C$ is one vector in $\mathbb F^M$.  It doesn't tell you anything about what $B$ does to vectors not in the span of $C$.  One family of solutions: take any $R \in \mathbb F^M$ with $R' C \ne 0$, and let $B = (R' C)^{-1} A R'$.  To that you can add any matrix whose null space contains $C$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!. May I please ask about the generic name of the approach you proposed. i am not very familiar with abstract notation (Fields, null space, etc.), but i will hopefully be able to learn all the related requirements if i am directed toward a reference to my question. Thank you again!